# Random choice in ML algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I'm new to AI and ML.

I am attempting to write code that will generate a decision tree given a random set of integers 0 - 9 as opposed to giving the code the choice between 0 and 1. Ideally, the code will output the likelihood (probability) of a pair of any two integers between 0 - 9.

the code is as follows:

```
from sklearn import tree
import random

num1 = random.randint (0, 9)
num2 = random.randint (0, 9)

X = [[num1, num1], [num2, num2]]
Y = [num1, num2]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

the program still outputs a decision tree from set of [0,1] and not random integers between 0 - 9.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `import random`

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct.

when you run the whole code along with  clf.predict(X)  the values in the set changes when you execute repeatedly, as you gave random function